# hadoop reducer in not getting distributed across clustor

Tags: java, cloudera, hadoop2, reducers

I have written a mapreduce job in java. The size of the input file is 2GB. When I run my code on a 8 node cluster, I get 16 slipts, which I can see from logs that these are running on DIFFERENT nodes. However, the reducer task is running only on "ONE node". I get output without any error. I checked my configurations all seems fine.

I tried with

- `job.setNumReduceTasks(100);`
- `-D mapreduce.job.reduces=100`

I get 100 output files too. MAPPER TASK IS DISTRIBUTED ACROSS NODES BUT NOT THE REDUCE TASK.

I am using cloudera services.

Comment: Can you please post your Mapper and Reducer classes. If you are getting 100 output files then the reducers are fine. May be your partitioning is wrong and all your keys are sent to a single reducer.Or you just have one Key so all the Mapper outputs are sent to just one reducer.

Comment: @PrabhuMoorthy i am not using any custom partitioner. i am using just mapper and the reducer. here is my mapper code snippet: JsonObject jobj=(JsonObject) parsor.parse(value.toString()); JsonElement Jkey=jobj.get("joining_key");
    JsonElement Jdate=jobj.get("date");
    if(Jkey!=null && Jdate!=null && Jcontent!=null && Jurl!=null && Jauthor!=null)
    {
       context.write(new Text(Jkey.getAsString()), value);
    }

Comment: @PrabhuMoorthy my key to the mapper output is the "joining_key". which will be same for some json documents. i am merging the json documents with the same "joining key" in the reducer.

Comment: @PrabhuMoorthy i think if all the keys go to one partitioner then the output will also go to one part-r file and rest 99 files will be empty. but every output file has data. means defualt paritioner is doing fair job. :)